# Angular App not loading on stock Android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, compatibility

I am working on a project built in Angular (1), and can confirm that it works in both Dev & Production environments across all of my desktop browsers, as well as my mobile ones (**Android**: Chrome, Firefox, Adblock Browser; **iOS**: Stock Browser, Firefox, Chrome). Unfortunately we have found that it is *not* loading in multiple people's stock Android browsers (I've personally tested it in DuOS 5.1.1, and on a couple different devices on Browserstack).

In looking through previous responses here on SO, I have taken some peoples' suggestions and added [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) with `require('core-js')` to our ***routes.js*** file (with `<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>` in our ***index.html***); but that did not seem to have any effect.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions for additional things I should try. I can post any portions of the code people think would be relevant; but it's a fairly large project (thousands of lines)

**[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz3Mz.jpg)**
On the left, working on my phone. On the right, not working on an emulated device.

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polyfills were not working, so in the end we decided to detect if users were on the Stock Android Browser - and, if they were, bringing them to a page recommending them to use Firefox, Chrome, etc to use the site/app.

Here is the code we used to do so:

```
    var navU = navigator.userAgent;
    // Android Mobile
    var isAndroidMobile = navU.indexOf('Android') > -1 && navU.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && navU.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1;
    // Apple webkit
    var regExAppleWebKit = new RegExp(/AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/);
    var resultAppleWebKitRegEx = regExAppleWebKit.exec(navU);
    var appleWebKitVersion = (resultAppleWebKitRegEx === null ? null : parseFloat(regExAppleWebKit.exec(navU)[1]));
    // Chrome
    var regExChrome = new RegExp(/Chrome\/([\d.]+)/);
    var resultChromeRegEx = regExChrome.exec(navU);
    var chromeVersion = (resultChromeRegEx === null ? null : parseFloat(regExChrome.exec(navU)[1]));
    // Native Android Browser
    var isAndroidBrowser = isAndroidMobile && (appleWebKitVersion !== null && appleWebKitVersion <= 537) || (chromeVersion !== null && chromeVersion <= 38);

    //If isAndroidBrowser, redirect 
    if(isAndroidBrowser){
        window.location = "/views/compatibility/compatibility.html";
    }
```